# How we can connect the wifi scan results to specific ssid network and want to launch app?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I have implemented code to get the wifi scan results & and tried to connect to particular specific networks which have good signal strength and after launching the app not able to open it.

## Ref link:

[WiFiActivity](https://github.com/zoltanersek/android-wifi-activity/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zoltanersek/androidwifiactivity/WifiActivity.java)

Please provide your suggestions, any clue or lead would be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, hope it'll work

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", key);

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
//remember id
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```